# Why does linguistics focus on spoken languages rather than written ones?

Tags: written-language

I might be wrong since I'm unable to find any sources supporting this, but it's increasingly my gut feeling that linguistics appears to focus on spoken languages as opposed to written ones. If this is the case, why is it?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean 'words' as opposed to other units/structures? Or do you mean 'spoken' as opposed to signed?

Comment: +1 @Gaston Ümlaut: Yes, I mean spoken, not signed. I had heard of a signed language that developed in isolation and was not taught, but that was on the radio; meaning afterwords I made no attempt to find the research, and was unable to find it yesterday. To address your concerns about the use of 'words', I change it to speech. Thanks for sharing your observations!

Comment: What do you mean by "Might be wrong..."? The title question, or what follows?

Comment: +1 @Mitch: Ha, okay - I've edited the body to in an attempt to address your concerns, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There is only one language with a written form but no spoken or signed form, and it's a constructed language with no native speakers as far as I know: [Blissymbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissymbols)

Comment: +1 @hippietrail: Thanks, was wondering if one existed.

Comment: @hippietrail, "no spoken [...] form, [...] with no native speakers". No wonder! Sorry, couldn't help myself.

Comment: @dainichi: You like my rhetorical technique for building emphasis? (-:

Comment: Linguistics may "focus" on spoken language (for reasons outlined by other people here), but that doesn't mean that written language is uninteresting or that it doesn't get studied at all. To my knowledge, text messaging e.g. has been extensively studied.

Comment: There are plenty of proposed symbolic "languages", most designed for putative alien contact. They're not really languages, any more than a Model T is a horse.

Comment: @blunders by the way, the signed language you might be referring to could be Nicagaruan Sign Language, whose development was somewhat spontaneous. The story behind it is very interesting and worth looking into on it's own.

Comment: Writing is not art. It is a technology. Linguists don’t study technologies.

Comment: @MilesRout All natural languages have equal value. Not the same idea at all.

Comment: @MilesRout My mistake. I should have written "value". Who even knows what the value of a language is? Really? There is no intrinsic value to any language.

Comment: In many languages, the word for "language" is actually "speech".  English "language" and "linguistics" also refer to the tongue, not to the pen, paper, letter, typewriter...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Linguistics is the scientific study of language. A language is narrowly defined as the set of rules that "speakers" (speaking or signing) acquire when they are very, very young. There is evidence for processes of language acquisition underway at the very youngest testable ages (under a year old).

A speaker with a grammar like mine *knows*, without ever being told, that strings of words like *colorless green ideas sleep furiously* are well-formed, but strings like *furiously sleep ideas green colorless* are not. I can say that the first sentence would be true if (i) there existed some things that were colorless, green, and ideas, (ii) such things could sleep, and (iii) such sleepings could happen furiously. The other string supports no such interpretation. Since I don't have to look up these two strings in some kind of book to tell whether one is good or bad, we say that my grammatical rules are internalized.

The rules of grammar (again, in the linguist's sense) are learned *implicitly*. They are not taught, as the rule "i before e except after c" has to be learned when one learns how to spell, but rather inferred on the basis of experience in a linguistic environment (i.e., a community of speakers who do some speaking in the presence of the child).

Lastly, knowledge of language is universal. Barring severe cognitive deficits or social deprivation, every normally-developing child acquires a native tongue.

Written language stands in sharp contrast: children learn to read and write much later (usually once they start attending school) than they learn to understand and produce spoken language; written language has no internalized rules, it reflects only the speakers' internal rules and, possibly, a speaker's regard for the prescriptive rules of style; written language has to be learned explicitly (often laboriously); and, written language is not universal—there are many, many people on this planet who have knowledge of language but can't read or write.

"Written language" is an artifact of (some) human cultures *who already had spoken languages*. Spoken language is definitional of our *species*, and it is this kind of species-specific capacity that linguists study. This is not to say that the capacity for writing is not complex; it is in fact *more* complex than the capacity for language, in that explaining how we can have writing systems requires in part an explanation of what the language we're writing down *is* in the first place.

Comment: Not necessarily disagreeing, but just wondering if you have a source, since e.g. Wikipedia doesn't seem to agree: "Language is the human capacity for acquiring and using complex systems of communication, and a language is **any specific example of such a system**. The scientific study of language is called linguistics." (highlighting mine)

Comment: Whoops, forgot the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language

Comment: That's just Wikipedia editors making sure people who haven't learned that spoken language is natural and written language artificial won't get their knickers into a twist right at the beginning of the piece. Seriously, omission is not definition; "language" is spoken. Some languages have written forms, but most don't, and most speakers of most languages are illiterate, as has always been the case. Literacy is modern technology.

Comment: This is a whole load of quack and the conclusion is wanting. We do not write in the language of "(some) human cultures who already had spoken languages".

Comment: @jlawler There's nothing more artificial about writing than spoken language. Both have arbitrary rules that are socially governed. Written language has to be learned explicitly but that doesn't mean it isn't language any more than it would be correct to say that written laws are less legitimately "laws" than unwritten conventions because people need to "explicitly learn them" - nobody would accept that. You can't justify this distinction by just choosing a bunch of ways in which written and spoken language are different and then assert that those are the operative boundaries of linguistics.

Comment: @MilesRout The laws are not the point. The point is that your language, like your binocular color vision, is a product of biological evolution, over hundreds of thousands of years, at least.  Both of them have "rules", but we can't break them, any more than we can "break" the law of gravity. Writing, on the other hand, is arbitrary and technological (and **recent**) and quite changeable quite rapidly. Like all technology, and like nothing biological, it has to be specially learned. If you can't see a difference there, too bad. I'm done talking about it.

Comment: @jlawler the fundamental difference is that writing is not just an arbitrary technology but a technology which is used to *convey language*. It has to be learnt - so what? That doesn't mean it isn't language. You're just picking arbitrary attributes that distinguish written and spoken language and deciding that they are the distinction between 'real language' and not.

Comment: @jlawler Of course there are differences between written and spoken language. Otherwise we wouldn't have different names for them. Pointing out that they are different doesn't automatically justify what you're saying, which is not 'they're different' but 'X is a legitimate object of study in the study of Z and Y is not' - merely pointing out that they are 'different' is nowhere near sufficient to justify your claim.

Comment: @jlawler As another example, sign languages are commonly held by linguists to be just as legitimate as spoken languages. You cannot argue that sign languages predate written language, or that they don't need to be learnt, or that they're not arbitrary, or that they are the product of biological evolution over hundreds of thousands of years.

Comment: Agreed, @MilesRout. This crusade against written languages is the most pseudo-science part of linguistics these past several decades, an example of motivated reasoning at its most deleterious. John's been pushing this BS for quite some time here, but thankfully more and better linguists don't agree with that nonsense.

Comment: @jlawler, I agree with you (Mar 19 at 16:52). A language (spoken form) is a product of the human biological system with social decisions made within the limitations of the biological system over hundreds of thousands of years at least. Sign languages are similar to it. However, the written form of a spoken language can be made with combinations of almost unlimited possibilities, such as of the Chinese characters. English has to be written with 26 letters. It is purely artificial. The decision to use the "26 letters" is not limited by any biological or biophysical capabilities.

Answer (score 12):

The attitude that spoken language is somehow primary to written (usually in a more general sense than geneologically) is known as [logocentrism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logocentrism) and has been extensively studied by, amongst others but arguably most famously, Jaques Derrida in his *Of Grammatology*.

Comment: I didn't realize the historical thread. Are you aware of what alternatives to this attitude might be?

Comment: I do not have great insight into linguistic practice, so take what I say with a grain of salt. That said I think there are at least two traditions which could reasonably be posed as alternatives. There is a study of language related to mathematical logic/formal language theory where one can study languages as certain kinds of formal structures. Alternatively it doesn't strike me as unreasonable to use semiotics as a "foundational theory" and consider linguistics as studying sign systems which certain "linguistic" qualities.

Comment: You'll sometimes hear the alternative referred to as *graphocentrism*. Outside of linguistics, "first world" culture tends to be pretty intensely graphocentric -- most non-linguists in, say, the US will feel like "Well, of *course* the *real* form of English is its written form!  That's why illiterate people talk funny!"  I don't think there's such a thing as "Graphocentric Linguistics," though.  Basically whatever a graphocentric researcher does, we're likely to say "Dude, that's not linguistics you're doing."

Comment: Note that an alternative does not need to subjugate spoken language  to written. I would say that both examples I stated earlier, rather, choose not to make such a judgement. (That's not to say that the comment on graphocentrism isn't relevant though.)

Comment: @TiloWiklund But spoken language _is_ primary to written. All writing systems are parasitic on language, most (maybe all) being systems for representing the phonemes of a given language. Linguists take the view that even spoken language is secondary, it being the knowledge inside the head that is truly primary--it is this knowledge that mathematical linguistics tries to model.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: It is precisely that attitude towards language (I'd say including the notion of an "internal" language) that people like Derrida have criticised. I'm not arguing for or against this view here (if I were I'd be very much on the side of people like Derrida, but this is not a discussion forum) but just mention that this phenomenon has been studied, has an established name and that not everyone "agrees" with it.

Comment: It's not an attitude; it's a fact. Spoken language is around a million years old, while writing of any kind dates from (being generous) ten thousand years ago. That's two orders of magnitude, not attitude. Derrida and his ilk are appropriately ignored by linguists. Facts come first, no matter how pretty the theory looks.

Comment: @jlawler The question was not about one form historically predating the other and as far as I am aware neither Derrida nor any scholar within his tradition have made any claims of written languages (at least in the narrow sense it is usually understood) predating spoken ones chronologically.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is ambiguous, so I'll just cast my net wide.

There is a lot of research into different aspects of language that don't necessarily involve speaking. Psycho- and neurolinguistics, both thriving subdisciplines, focus their efforts on understanding the psychological and neurological components of language production and processing. Morphology, phonology and syntax focus on the rules that govern the production of language, not necessarily the particular modality of production. A lot of language acquisition research, such as that focusing on how babies process pointing gestures or gazes, or on the strategies that children use to learn a language, has very little to do with spoken language.

A lot of disciplines that *prima facia* deal with spoken language, such as phonetics or phonology, can and have been successfully adapted to sign languages. For example: research has shown that their are sign language analogues for place and manner of articulation, and that sign language has units of production that can be rightfully refereed to as phonemes.

Written language is a reflection of spoken, so most of what we know about spoken language can be transfered to written. The converse is not true. Still, there is a great deal of research focusing on how written language is processed.

Spoken language is a part of what makes us human. Every child will become fluent in their native language unless they suffer from massive cognitive or social deficits. Even mentally retarded children, or others with low IQ's, still achieve a great deal of fluency. If someone is deaf or mute, they will either acquire or invent a signed language. Acquiring literacy, on the other hand, is laborious process. Most languages do not have a written form, and even in those that do, not everyone achieves literacy. Spoken language is more widespread and universal, and therefore more interesting than the mostly cultural invention we call 'writing'.

Finally, a lot of linguistics *has* to be done with spoken language. A lot of phonetics, for instance, is about sound production, transmission, and perception. Children learn spoken language far earlier than written language, so most interesting research on language acquisition is about spoken or signed language. As I pointed out above, most languages do not have a written form, so any linguistic research concerning them has to focus on their spoken forms.

Comment: I would argue that the term 'written language' does not make sense, at least in linguistic terms. There is no 'written language', only orthographies: arbitrary sets of symbols that are used to represent some aspect of (usually spoken) language. There are only really two types of language: spoken and signed (there is sometimes mention of 'whistle languages', but I don't know anything about them).

Comment: +1 @Gaston Ümlaut: That's pretty much the reasoning I thought to be behind Why linguistics appears focus on spoken languages. Would it be possible for you to state that in an answer an, expand on it, and provide sources supporting this claim? Thanks!

Comment: +1 @Nathan: I've heard that if someone is deaf or mute, they will either invent a signed language too. Do you know of any research related to this, and if so, would it be possible to add references to it. Thanks!

Comment: @blunders [Nicaraguan Sign Langauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_Sign_Language) is probably the best example. The phenomenon you are referring to is called [home sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_sign).

Comment: +1 @Nathan: Yes, I believe you're correct, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Many linguists focus on the spoken language indeed, or at least they claim to. Often times, Ferdinand de Saussure is attributed with, among other things, steering linguistics into this direction around the turn of the 20th century. Alas, for many years to come, linguists saying they’re studying the spoken language were instead relying on written records thereof. This remains a problem today, although the methods of transcription have improved and modern technology makes spoken language better accessible to direct analysis. Yet still, it’s much easier to generate corpora from written sources. As a result, most books(!) on grammar describe literal grammar, not oral grammar, which can be *very* different – therefore many people (even some linguists) will regard perfectly well-formed oral utterances as “grammatically wrong” or “ungrammatical”. (Note the etymology of *grammar*.)

There’s the interesting notion of conceptually and medially oral and literal languages, prominently by Koch/Oesterreicher. That means, a book is written in concept and medium, like a face-to-face conversation is spoken in both, but a formal speech is conceptually literal and medially oral, whereas a chat message usually is conceptually oral and medially literal.

Of course, gesture/sign language is primary to orally spoken language which in turn is primary to written language. This is true both phylogenetically for humankind and ontogenetically for each individual (even though you can learn a second language in literal form). The fact that writing was created, hence is an artifact, doesn’t mean it’s mere recording of speech (nor thought, as some believe), though. The (conceptually) written form of language developed specific rules that don’t apply to the spoken modality. There are also several things that one can only do in writing proper, although Ong, Watt and many more have provided interesting examples of what spoken language is capable of (especially in non-literate societies).

Many languages, most probably, aren’t written at all, i.e. they may be transcribed sometimes, mostly by linguists, priests and administrators, but conversation and “literature” is oral/aural only. That doesn’t require the society to be illiterate at all, since written communication is then often done in a different language. For these, it doesn’t make much sense to study their writing separately, but for most European, many Asian and some other contemporary languages, their writing system (incl. orthography and script) and written grammar are independent objects of linguistic study.

Comment: `(even some linguists) will regard perfectly well-formed oral utterances as “grammatically wrong” or “ungrammatical”` - I think this claim needs some supporting information. `Note the etymology of grammar.` - see ["Etymological fallacy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: I’m not saying they’re good linguists, they should know better, but it still happens all the time, even if they try to be descriptive. There’s also the occasional linguist who narrows the meaning of *ungrammatical* (as a technical term) or ‹*› to ‘not accepted in formal writing’. The etymology note is just a symptomatic fun fact; convention always tops history, of course.

Comment: I was going to upvote until I got to "gesture/sign language is primary to orally spoken language which in turn is primary to written language. This is true both phylogenetically for humankind and ontogenetically for each individual." As far as I know, there is no consensus that gestural *language* is the evolutionary precursor of spoken language, and it seems definitely *false* to say that each individual learns a gestural *language* before learning a spoken language. Hearing babies being raised by hearing adults generally don't learn gestural languages at all.

Comment: ...hearing babies may all make use of gestures to communicate before learning spoken language, but not all communication is "language".

Comment: @sumelic I may be biased by my academic training, but if you teach them both simultaneously, babies will acquire articulate gestures and sign language prior to pronounced sounds and vocal language.

Comment: @Crissov: I don't dispute that babies can acquire gestures and sign language. I don't know, but I'm prepared to believe that babies can learn to articulate sign gestures sooner than speech. But it's definitely not true to say that every baby learns a sign/gestural language before learning spoken language.

Comment: It's incredibly ironic that you're criticising people for being prescriptivist and at the same time being incredibly prescriptivist in your use of 'ungrammatical' by appealing to etymology.

Comment: @MilesRout I'm not at all prescriptivist about _grammatical_. I just pointed out that it was coined as a term within a mindset that favored written language as primary.

Answer (score 3):

To make an analogy, spoken language is like a hand and written language is like a hammer.

We are born with the capability to speak/hear (specific anatomical structures in the ear, mouth/throat/lungs, and brain) and we spontaneously learn spoken language by its presence. But writing systems are artificial, man-made contrivances, a coding system to record the spoken language, a tool that attempts to extend the usefulness of spoken language.

One naturally learns language growing up around people, but one needs instruction in reading and writing to do it. People communicated for thousands of years quite well without writing. The rules of writing are totally dependent on those of language that came before it.

To understand the arbitrariness of writing consider that Mandarin is normally expressed in logograms (the complicated picture-like collection of strokes for one syllable), but can also be expressed in pinyin, a romanization, roughly one letter per phoneme. Similarly, Persian is normally written in an Arabic script (leaving out most vowels) where Arabic is a very different structured language, but before the Arabic invasion was written in cuneiform, a syllabic system, but can be transcribed to a roman lettering. All these forms are with no change in meaning. The point is that writing systems are arbitrary inventions.

Writing is merely an attempt at encoding natural language (the non-written, primary, spoken thing). So, studying writing is studying the arbitrary man-made patterns of orthography, and these structures are very different from (or, if not, depend entirely on) the patterns of spoken language.

Studying writing (an interesting topic) is like studying a hammer, a very different thing than studying the hand that uses it.

---

As an aside, sign language needs to be accounted for (only because it is nominally not spoken), and that account (by analysis and experiment) seems to be that it has the same properties as spoken language in contrast to written ones.

For reference, see the preface/first chapter of any introductory linguistics textbook. There is the [speech and writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics#Speech_and_writing) section of wikipedia, which supports what I say, but you should seen actual authority to be convinced if you need a trustable reference.

Comment: +1 @Mitch: Believe your answer is close, but think it might be more clear to say it would be possible for humans to create a written language, the wiring of humans and the functions of that wiring make the benefits of spoken languages much more likely, so much so, that there are no know languages that were born from a writing system. While babies maybe able to sign before using a spoken language, the benefits of spoken language quickly over take there usuage of hand signing expressions. Right, or no?

Comment: @blunders, it's important to keep environmental factors in mind. If the baby is surrounded by adults who use speech as their main mode of communication, then the benefits of spoken language indeed overtake those of sign language. But if the baby is born into a community of adults who are deaf, that will not be true. It is not clear to me that, as a self-contained system, a spoken language has any advantages over a signed one in terms of its communicative effectiveness, provided that the respective levels of competence of the message sender and message recipient are controlled for.

Comment: @blunders: re babies - One of my points was that as far as this question is concerned sign language (using arm and facial gestures) is in the same category as spoken language, and that category is very far away from the category of writing (as a means of communication). So I think it is a non sequitur by talking about the learning of sign or spoken languages in babies (an interesting separate question).

Comment: @blunders: re 'wiring' - forgetting the physical expression (sight vs sound, the 'wiring' for writing is qualitatively very different from the 'wiring' for language, so 'much more likely' is just a extreme understatement. Even people with very dysfunctional nervous systems can do spoken language, and high brain functioning people can have difficulties learning reading/writing (have you learned Chinese lately?).

Comment: @blunders: to be intellectually honest, one could say that all known [constructed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) (Esperanto, Lojban, Klingon) were created out of a writing tradition. But those could only be considered true languages when they are passed to a child as a first language. And that will surely only ever occur as a -spoken- language. The writing (orthography, character shapes, visual transfer) is secondary to the language properties.

Comment: +1 @musicallinguist: Spoken languages do not require line-of-sight, signed languages on the other hand do. For example, in a culture that used sign language, it would not be possible to yell stop at a child approaching some danger. It's also technology wise to project and record sound waves than gestures; or at least in my opinion. Again, this is not to say it's not possible, but that given the wiring of humans, the evolution of a spoken language is much more likely barring factors that change that likelihood; again just my opinion.

Comment: +3 @Mitch: Ha, guess Esperanto is a "true" language, since there are 200–2000 people who speak Esperanto as a first language; see [Native Esperanto speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Esperanto_speakers).

Comment: There is also one native Klingon speaker, spoken to only in Klingon by his father until he reached an age where he was able to tell his father to quit being so weird and just speak English like everybody else!

Comment: @hippietrail: Would that be the child of linguist [d’Armond Speers](http://www.mndaily.com/2009/11/17/local-company-creates-klingon-dictionary), and his son Alec - or another native speaker? It unclear if Klingon really was his first language, since his mother spoke English to him too. d’Armond states the reason he stopped speaking Klingon with his son was because his son stopped responding to anything in Klingon. [Dejpu'bogh Hov rur qablli!](http://www.wired.com/wired/archive/4.08/es.languages.html)

Comment: @blunders: Yes it seems you have the true facts on this story! As to whether a bilingual learning one language from the mother and one from the father only has the mother's language as their first language, that seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: *“one needs instruction in reading and writing to do it”* — Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: @Timwi: That's wonderfully skeptical. The only test I can think of is if you would mind reading some [Linear A](http://www.ancientscripts.com/lineara.html).

Comment: @Mitch: I’m pretty sure I could learn to read Linear A if I were 5–7 years old and immersed in an entire culture that uses it. If that already counts as “needing instruction”, then clearly learning to *speak* needs instruction too — or do you think you could learn to speak Proto-Sino-Tibetan merely by hearing a few contextless sound recordings of it?

Comment: @Timwi: I suppose my example was inappropriate. A three year old can learn to speak, in context, any language in the world, spoken or sign. In the -same- context, 3 year olds can barely do letters -even knowing already the language the alphabet is supposed to encode-. (assuming an alphabet which is much easier than logograms like Chinese/Egyptian/Mayan).

Comment: @Mitch: Well your claim wasn’t restricted to 3-year-olds. You said *one needs instruction in reading and writing to do it.* I challenge that claim, not least because counter-examples are known to occur. It may well be the case that these are just exceptional outliers, but we don’t know that; we have no way of measuring how many people would have learned writing (by age 12, say) without schooling if it weren’t mandatory at age 6.

Comment: There are several reports of famous authors first learning to read upside-down and backwards, because they learned from watching papa reading the Bible to the family,  Evidently, one can learn reading from observation, without instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Speech is thousands of years older than writing (the earliest known writing is Sumerian cuneiform -pictographs inscribed in clay). So it has primacy over the written word. According to Crystal (2003:178-9) both speech and writing are recognised as 'alternative, equal systems of linguistic expressions'. Focus on writing is characterised by studies in to literature and therefore style, genre and, perhaps, the notion of linguistic excellence and standards. Historically, speech was not considered worthy of study. In modern times, there has been much wider analysis of speech for a number of reasons:
1. Prevalence of 'second' language learning.
2. Investigations in to primary language acquisition.
3. Cognitive studies in to speech and the language centre of the brain.
4. Striving for improved standards and teaching methodologies.
5. etc..

or perhaps for the very fact that not a lot of academic attention had been paid to it before.

Speech is an innate skill that manifests itself without a formal learned environment (taking Krashen's distinction on 'acquisition' and 'learning'). Writing is a learned skill in formal learning settings. Children must learn to talk before they can write. So the primary focus in research is naturally on speech as the starting point of language acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

That is because:

1. Writing is a relatively recent development.
2. Although we acquire speech without conscious effort, learning to read and write is usually less spontaneous and less automatic.
3. All of us speak a great deal more than we write.
4. Thousands of speech communities rely solely on speech.
5. Writing is permanent while speech is instant.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE. Although the claims might be true, we appreciate more detailed answers, based on scientific references. Please improve yours by adding further details. Check other answers for more examples.

Comment: Why aren't these facts reasons to focus on written language? Identifying a set of facts about speech vs. writing doesn't actually answer the why question. Connect the dots.

Comment: These facts are reasons to distinguish the relative importance and systematicity of spoken English, versus the relative unimportance and arbitrary nature of written English. Written language is studied -- [Daniels and Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World%27s_Writing_Systems) is a standard -- but it's not important, except historically.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivially true that children learn to speak before learning to write. This results in an intuitively true cause for the impression that linguistics is focused more on oral speach than other forms, because the priority is an inherint property of the system—there's a little linguist in everyone.

It is still questionable for various reasons, eg. how to quantify this judgement empirically.

It's leass clear if, as @Crissov argues, gesture/sign language is acquired even earlier. A broader, stronger statement might be that a general ability for communication *by any means necessary* begins developing before any elaborate language emerges. It is trivially true because sign languages don't require oral speech, and it is economical because it doesn't give preference to any one system.

Comment: Just to be clear, every non-blind infant who is regularly exposed to hand-signed language (in addition to the abundant oral language) will achieve some easy to observe proficiency first in the sign language, in both production and reception, and without significantly affecting their acquisition of the vocal language in either way. However, few babies live this experience nowadays and I never claimed otherwise, i.e. not every kid signs (first). It’s not a stretch to postulate that this individual, ontogenetic precedence suggests evolutionary, phylogenetic precedence, which can’t be (dis)proven.

Answer (score 0):

As a student of mostly dead "classical" languages, most of the "linguistics" I did encounter, was and is historic linguistics aiming at a reconstruction of a postulated "proto"-language, predating the known and handed down languages, which again predate the spoken languages of today.

Now, while from my perspective of a semi- to quarter-linguist it makes perfect sense, that linguistics should focus on language as opposed to literature (or: "art", as esoneill put it), already the question struck me as quite absurd (regarding my experience), since the linguistics I know does not only not focus on spoken language but even near-totally suppresses any reference to "language" as something spoken rather than written. This is, of course, because of the fact, that written evidence endures much longer than the sound of an utterance and so is the only available data for this sort of historical linguistics.

Still, sometimes even here, stress is laid on the spoken languages. Of course not so much in what concerns "proto"-languages, but there are, for example, attempts to reconstruct the phonology of (Vedic) Sanskrit and it is quite well known that Classical Sanskrit never was a spoken language at all. (Incidentally, this holds true for most of the "classical" Indian languages). This kind of reverses the modern approach to languages, reflected in the answers already given: spoken language is here only appended and ancillary to the written.

Comment: But the Indians invented a writing system that actually represented the sounds, and they kept the pronunciation alive for centuries by using phonetic description. That they idealized the language is inevitable in a religious context; but they made every effort -- far more than the Greeks or Romans, or modern English speakers, for that matter -- to actually present the spoken language properly. And it's paid off, in terms of the information that's available to moderns about original pronunciations.

Comment: Well, I do doubt this. Brahmi and Kharoshthi were modelled on the Paninian grammar that reflects the phoneme inventory of Classical Sanskrit, as stated a language, that was never spoken but has been an artificial language right from the beginning. It is quite obvious that the script failed to represent all sounds of even the languages spoken at the time of invention. For example Pali (still predating writing and artificial itself) has short e and o, which do not figure in most Indian scripts (and not in the ones used at that time). The situation worsens with later Prakrits and Apabhramsha.

Comment: The same can be said, even more so, about any language of antiquity. We have no evidence that any human being ever **spoke** (as opposed to recited, read, or wrote) Homeric Greek or Classical Latin, nor how well they were understood, nor by whom. All our evidence is written -- which refers to the OQ. There are always dialects, and there are always sociolects, in any spoken language; among them they probly display all the variation one needs. We have no idea how the lower classes actually talked in any ancient civilization, and it is the lower classes that drive language change.

Comment: By the way: Brahmi and Kharoshthi, the first Indic scripts, even though having been modelled on Panini both supply no way of writing double, triple, quadruple consonants...

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty simple, actually.

Spoken language is a natural phenomenon; written language is a craft or art form.

There's a pretty strong divide here among the natural sciences. Chemists don't study Money; physicists don't study Beethoven.

Linguists don't study written language (generally) because written language isn't language — it's art.

Comment: that's not true. do you really think every E-Mail, every Facebook comment, every text message is "art"? No. It clearly is communication, as is any face-to-face conversation.

Comment: @Fryie: I think it's fair to interpret that esoneill's first language is not English or that the best word, *artefact*, can be a bit elusive even to native speakers.

Comment: _Art:_ Conscious direction of means to an end. Covers writing. Covers technology. Covers fine arts and literature. Doesn't cover language, any more than it covers walking. They come with the territory. Derrida's supposed "graphology" is a theory of art, while linguistics is a theory of language. There are facts in linguistics, as well as attitudes.